# receive in a php(server) a POST send by java (client)

Tags: php, xml

i want to receive in a server a xml file sent by java by POST

how can e receive that ? and how can e parse the file, in this case a xml file...

regards.

Comment: Can we get more details?  Is this a file upload, are you trying to implement a web service?

Comment: i just want to sent a file to a server in php by a client in java..

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous tutorials on handling file uploads (including: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php ) if you're actually uploading a file. If, instead, you're posting the contents of the file, the contents will be in the $_POST and $_REQUEST arrays - PHP creates and populates these for you.

This is a broad (and basic) question, so a more specific answer will require you to read some tutorials, try some code, and post specific questions about problems you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a file upload (`enctype="multipart/form-data"`), use the `$_FILES` superglobal: [Handling File Uploads](https://www.php.net/file-upload).

Otherwise, just refer to it by its form field name: `$_POST['xmlfile']`.

Either way, parse it using the [DOM](https://www.php.net/dom) or [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/simplexml).

Answer (score 0):

if it's XMLRPC request, you have to use either $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA or php://input wrapper.